How to make Dependabot to not update from SNAPSHOT?
Let's imaging I have a dependency like:
mavenBom "org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:6.2.0-SNAPSHOT"

The Spring Framework has just released 6.2.0 GA and just after that published 6.2.1-SNAPSHOT.
Ideally I would like Dependabot to suggest me an update to 6.2.0, but that's different story.
Right now I just don't want it to update from 6.2.0-SNAPSHOT to 6.2.1-SNAPSHOT.
What kind of config I could apply to skip such a version pattern from updating?
My current one is like this:
ignore:
  - dependency-name: '*'
    update-types:
      - version-update:semver-major
      - version-update:semver-minor 

Doesn't look like versions option can accept something like *-SNAPSHOT: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#specifying-dependencies-and-versions-to-ignore
UPDATE
Well, apparently there is no way for now. Found this old GH issue: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/7885

version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "maven"  # Use 'maven' or 'gradle' as per your project
    directory: "/"  # Adjust to your project directory if needed
    schedule:
      interval: "weekly"  # Set to 'daily', 'weekly', or 'monthly'
    versioning-strategy: "increase"  # Prevent SNAPSHOT versions from being picked
    ignore:
      - dependency-name: "your-dependency"  # Optional: Ignore specific dependencies
        versions: ["*-SNAPSHOT"]  # Ignore SNAPSHOT versions


Thanks. Looks like you have posted a YAML for Dependabot config. Would you mind modifying it as a code, so it becomes readable in your answer?

Looks like versioning-strategy is not supported for Maven/Gradle: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#versioning-strategy. Or that doc has not been updated...

Just tested that with versions: ["*-SNAPSHOT"]. Failed like this: The property '#/updates/0/ignore/0/versions' includes invalid version requirements for a gradle ignore condition. So, this answer is not correct. Sorry.
